# JSON will not insert into Meteor Collection (even with Fiber or bindEnvironment)

Tags: meteor, coffeescript, fiber

I realize that similar topics have been discussed, I have browsed through them all and tried to mimic solutions for about 4 hours but none of them seem to solve the problem. I would not have posted this with having exhausted any potential solution I could find.

I am trying to convert a large csv to JSON and then insert it into my Meteor collection following the conversion.

Here is my code using the Meteor.bindElement approach:

```
if Meteor.isServer
    @Fiber = Meteor.npmRequire("fibers")
    Meteor.startup ->
    #Converter Class
         if Data.find().count() is 0
             Converter = Meteor.npmRequire('csvtojson').core.Converter
             fs = Meteor.npmRequire('fs')
             csvFileName = '/Path/To/My/File.csv'
             fileStream = fs.createReadStream(csvFileName)
             #new converter instance
             csvConverter = new Converter(constructResult: true)
             #end_parsed will be emitted once parsing finished
             csvConverter.on "end_parsed", (jsonObj) ->
                 console.log jsonObj
                 boundFunction = Meteor.bindEnvironment(->
                     Data.insert jsonObj
                     return
                 , (e) ->
                      throw e
                      return
                 )

                 insertToDB boundFunction
                 #read from file
             fileStream.pipe csvConverter
         return
```

After parsing I am able to log the JSON just fine but when I try to add it to the collection like this:

```
csvConverter.on "end_parsed", (jsonObj) ->
    console.log jsonObj
    Data.insert jsonObj
```

I get the error:

```
throw new Error("Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. " +          
W20141112-20:08:44.306(-8)? (STDERR)           ^
W20141112-20:08:44.306(-8)? (STDERR) Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment.
W20141112-20:08:44.306(-8)? (STDERR)     at Object.Meteor._nodeCodeMustBeInFiber (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:9)
W20141112-20:08:44.306(-8)? (STDERR)     at _.extend.get  (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:21)
W20141112-20:08:44.306(-8)? (STDERR)     at Object.DDP.randomStream (packages/ddp/random_stream.js:69)
W20141112-20:08:44.306(-8)? (STDERR)     at self._makeNewID (packages/mongo/collection.js:72)
W20141112-20:08:44.306(-8)? (STDERR)     at Mongo.Collection.(anonymous function) [as insert] (packages/mongo/collection.js:485)
W20141112-20:08:44.307(-8)? (STDERR)     at csvAdv.<anonymous> (server/startup.coffee:16:13)
W20141112-20:08:44.307(-8)? (STDERR)     at csvAdv.emit (events.js:95:17)
W20141112-20:08:44.307(-8)? (STDERR)     at csvAdv.<anonymous> (/Users/samuel_chordas/CurrentClasses/CSCI477a/JPL/JataTwo/packages/npm-container/.build.npm-container/npm/node_modules/csvtojson/libs/core/init_onend.js:9:10)
W20141112-20:08:44.307(-8)? (STDERR)     at csvAdv.emit (events.js:117:20)
W20141112-20:08:44.307(-8)? (STDERR)     at _stream_readable.js:929:16
=> Exited with code: 8
```

Which I was able to get rid of by wrapping the function in a fiber with the following code but it DOES NOT write to my collection:

```
if Meteor.isServer
    @Fiber = Meteor.npmRequire("fibers")
    Meteor.startup ->
    #Converter Class
        if Data.find().count() is 0
            Converter = Meteor.npmRequire('csvtojson').core.Converter
            fs = Meteor.npmRequire('fs')
            csvFileName = '/Path/To/My/File.csv'
            fileStream = fs.createReadStream(csvFileName)
            #new converter instance
            csvConverter = new Converter(constructResult: true)
            #end_parsed will be emitted once parsing finished
            csvConverter.on "end_parsed", (jsonObj) ->
                Fiber ->
                    Data.insert jsonObj
                return
            fileStream.pipe csvConverter
        return
```

So I tried resorting to using the bindEnvironment as shown in the first block of code which results in the same "Error("Meteor code must always run within a Fiber" error.

Here is my collection in my /lib folder:

```
@Data = new Mongo.Collection 'data'
```

I am pretty new to Meteor Javascript and Coffescript so any feedback would be appreciated.

Also I would like to add that I can't get .run() to work on Fiber.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to parse the csv outside of meteor and put the resulting json file into your `private` dir so you can use the [assets](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/assets) api to read in the file. I can give an example as an answer if that sounds like an acceptable alternative.

Comment: @DavidWeldon The solution below worked but I would still like the example incase we need to use that method later if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the definition of `boundFunction` outside of the `end_parsed` event handler.

```coffee
boundFunction = Meteor.bindEnvironment((jsonObj) ->
  Data.insert jsonObj
  return
, (e) ->
  throw e
)

csvConverter.on "end_parsed", (jsonObj) ->
  console.log jsonObj
  boundFunction jsonObj
  return
```

I suspect the "Meteor code must always run within a Fiber." error is not coming from `Data.insert` but from `Meteor.bindEnvironment` itself. `Meteor.bindEnvironment`

- is called from inside a "Meteor context"
- takes a function
- binds that function to the same "Meteor context" that `bindEnvironment` was called from

In your implementation, by the time you call `bindEnvironment`, the "Meteor context" has already been lost, so `bindEnvironment` can't do anything to help.

Comment: This worked! Thank you! The issue now is that we are overflowing the primary key but that's totally separate. Thanks again.